# Display multiple content items from an unordered list with javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html-lists, slide, fade

I would like to make the following code display 3 of the 6 list items at a time, instead of just one, chronologically. This is example item content:

```
<ul id="newgall">
    <li>
        <div class="newsblock">ITEM CONTENT 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="newsblock">ITEM CONTENT 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="newsblock">ITEM CONTENT 3</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="newsblock">ITEM CONTENT 4</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="newsblock">ITEM CONTENT 5</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="newsblock">ITEM CONTENT 6</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I use the following script:

```
$('#newgall li:first').addClass('curr');
$('#newgall li:not(:first)').hide();

var slide = function () {
    var Act_curr = $('#newgall li.curr');
    Act_curr.hide().removeClass('curr');

    if (Act_curr.next()[0] && Act_curr.next()[0].nodeName == 'LI') {
        Act_curr.next().show('fade').addClass('curr');
    } else {
        $('#newgall li:first').addClass('curr').show('fade');
    }
    setTimeout(slide, 4500);
};

slide();
```

The ultimate hope is use this as recent posts ticker for WordPress. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) operator to calculate index of the LI to be shown on each step. For example:

```
var $items = $('#newgall li'),
    i = 0;

function slide() {
    var index = i % $items.length;
    $items.hide().removeClass('curr').slice(index, index +3).show('fade').addClass('curr');
    i += 3;
    setTimeout(slide, 4000);
};

slide();
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JjVbpApDDAASpSkEnxJh?p=preview

Comment: [dfsq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq), thank you for the very quick response! This is exactly what I am looking for. If you do not mind, please take a peak at my new question. It is a little more specific to the goal I am trying to accomplish. This answer is sufficient for static lists, but i am working with dynamic lists from queries. Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170183/display-multiple-sets-of-content-items-a-from-a-wordpress-query-with-javascript) if you think you can help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the list to increment by one item at a time as opposed to in groups of three, you can use:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
    $('#newgall li:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass('curr');    
}
$('#newgall li:not(.curr)').hide();

var slide = function () {
    var Act_curr = $('#newgall li.curr:eq(0)');
    var newItem = $('#newgall li.curr:eq(2)');

    Act_curr.hide().removeClass('curr');

    if (newItem.next()[0] && newItem.next()[0].nodeName == 'LI') {
        newItem.next().show('fade').addClass('curr');
    } else {
        $('#newgall .curr').removeClass('curr').hide();
        $('#newgall li:first').addClass('curr').show('fade');
        $('#newgall li:nth-child(2)').addClass('curr').show('fade');
        $('#newgall li:nth-child(3)').addClass('curr').show('fade');
    }
    setTimeout(slide, 4500);
};

slide();
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/buzayili/1/edit)

Comment: [LLoyd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1423787/lloyd-banks), thank you for the quick response! If you do not mind, please take a peak at my new question. It is a little more specific to the goal I am trying to accomplish. I am working with dynamic lists from queries. Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170183/display-multiple-sets-of-content-items-a-from-a-wordpress-query-with-javascript) if you think you can help. I wouldn't mind having the answer in the style of code you and I originally used to accomplish the effect. Thanks again!